# DEX Graph Database with C#: Are there any code examples for graph export?

Tags: c#, graph-databases

I started to use DEX Graph database with C#. So far I have managed to run simple examples, but can't find out how to export the graph.

I would like to export the graph to Graphviz format in order to display it with other visualization tools. Does anyone know any good resource where an example of graph export could be found or has perhaps anyone of you already managed to export the graph and could share the code?

I would be very thankful for your help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a simple default exporter that can be used this way:

```
DefaultExport exp = new DefaultExport();
graph.Export("exported.gv", ExportType.Graphviz, exp);
```

But to get a better output you may need to code your own exporter extending the [ExportManager](http://www.sparsity-technologies.com/downloads/doc-net/html/classcom_1_1sparsity_1_1dex_1_1gdb_1_1ExportManager.html) class.

And you can ask in the company [forum](http://www.sparsity-technologies.com/dextechsupport/) if you have problems.

Answer (score 0):

To make your own exporter you should do something like this:

```
public class MyExport : ExportManager
    {
        private Graph g = null;

        public MyExport() {
        }

        public override void Prepare(Graph graph) {
            // This method will be called once at the beginning of the export.
            // So we keep the graph being exported.
            g = graph;

        }

        public override void Release() {
            // Called once at the end of the export process.
        }

        public override bool GetGraph(GraphExport graphExport) {
            // Called once to get the Graph details (a label)
            graphExport.SetLabel("[MyExport] MyGraph");
            return true;
        }

        public override bool EnableType(int type) {
            // Will be called once for each type to allow or deny the export of
            // the nodes/edges of each type
            return true; // We enable the export of all types
        }


        public override bool GetNode(long node, NodeExport nodeExport) {
            // Called once for each node of an allowed type to get it's export definition.
            // The definition will be used if it returns true, or the default
            // node type definition from getNodeType will be used if this method
            // returns false.
            // It can set the label, shape, color, ...
            nodeExport.SetLabel("[MyExport] MyNode " + node);
            return true;
        }

        public override bool GetNodeType(int type, NodeExport nodeExport) {
            // Used to get a node type generic export definition.
            // Called once for each node only if the call to GetNode returned false.
            // It can set the label, shape, color, ...
            nodeExport.SetLabel("[MyExport] MyNodeType " + type);
            return true;
        }

        public override bool GetEdge(long edge, EdgeExport edgeExport) {
            // Called once for each edge of an allowed type to get it's export definition.
            // The definition will be used if it returns true, or the default
            // edge type definition from getEdgeType will be used if this method
            // returns false.
            // It can set the label, shape, color, ...
            edgeExport.SetLabel("[MyExport] MyEdge " + edge);
            return true;
        }

        public override bool GetEdgeType(int type, EdgeExport edgeExport) {
            // Used to get an edge type generic export definition.
            // Called once for each edge only if the call to GetEdge returned false.
            // It can set the label, shape, color, ...
            edgeExport.SetLabel("[MyExport] MyEdgeType " + type);
            return true;
        }
    }
```

I'm afraid that for graphviz the exporter only accepts changing labels. For colors and shapes, ... maybe you can consider using ygraphml exportation?